# App name "By xxx" (iTunes Connect)

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am about to submit an App to the App Store and I am wondering if the "By WhatsApp Inc." (in the top left, under the app name) is coming from the Company name. (see attached screenshot)

How can I update that information in the iTunes Connect? I am not able to find updated details and this page is the only one which is talking about that (and the screenshots are not up to date)

[Decide On Your Company's name](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html)

Thank you

[image]

Comment: __you can't.__ you need to register a new individual or a company account and you can set the developer's name then for that account only _once_, you can also transfer your existing apps from you current account to your new one flawlessly. an individual account always has your name as developer, for a company account you need to present the legal documents of your registered company to Apple to approve to use that name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't need to transfer any app, I have already a company's account and I just need to know where is that information coming from.